# Probabilistic Random Numbers?

Tags: flash, random, flash-cs5, actionscript-3

So, I have a problem. Basically, I didn't pay enough attention in high school math, and now I'm stuck. I need to generate random numbers between 1 adn 20 with a heavy emphasis on the one between 1 and 5, a light emphasis on 5-10, and a low emphasis on 10-20. I don't understand all the fancy probability words and all the stuff they say in the articles I've come across. Any help you guys can provide would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: there have been several questions on this topic on SO....

Comment: Actually, I've been programming for 5 or 6 years now, and I just have a simple math question. Unless you have something useful to add, comments aren't appreciated.

Comment: @Jack Being aggressive probably isn't the best way to get the answer I was about half way through for you..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't usually get mad, but insulting me isn't going to help.

Comment: Either or, it doesn't really matter. Integers, ideally, between 1 and 20. But I can (and by the looks of it, might have to) deal with floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula to generate a random number in the range [low, high]:

```
var randomNumber:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+high-low))+low;
```

You can put that in a function if you want.

Now, an easy way to have a different probability for the three intervals you provided, is to do something like this:

```
var random:Number = Math.random();
if (random < 0.75) {
    // generate random number in [1, 5]
} else if (random < 0.95) {
    // generate random number in [6, 10]
} else {
    // generate random number in [11, 20]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something along the lines below if you needed a "smooth" distribution. I.e. the distribution would gradually vary between the lowest and highest values with the emphasis in the case below would be on the lower values.

```
    private function univenlyDistributedRandom(low:int, high:int):Number
    {
        return low + (1 - Math.pow(Math.random(), 4)) * (high - low);           
    }
```

You could, of course, use any other function (hyperbole, or sine etc) to generate slightly different variations. One funny thing though. If you are using any kind of tweening engine - you probably already have those kinds of functions! Any easing function that is not linear applied to the output of the `Math.random()` would affect the distribution in a "smooth" way. So, if, for example, you see that the easing function does something like "it goes slow at first, but then faster, faster, and even more faster", that would mean that the distribution you could achieve with it would be biased towards the smaller numbers and the bigger numbers would occur less often.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the penner equation.
http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/

Generate a number between 0 and 1.
Give it to the penner equation, it will return a number between 0 and 1.
Multiply this number by the max value you want.
Round it.

```
number = Math.round(MyTransformFunction(Math.random())*MaxNumber)

function MyTransformFunction(x){
   return x*x;
}
```

Any other functions that return a number between 0-1 for an input between 0-1 will work :

```
return -x*x;
return Math.sqrt(x);
```